# Reading *.xls file throws BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream

Tags: java, excel, swing

I created a `.xls` file. When I read it and add data to it using Swing, it is working fine .

But after adding values to `xls` if I want to read it again it is throwing the following error

```
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:116)
at jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:127)
at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)
at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
at codes.OperationClass.getTableReady(OperationClass.java:34)
at designs.ViewStock.RButtonAllStockActionPerformed(ViewStock.java:181)
at designs.ViewStock.access$0(ViewStock.java:180)
at designs.ViewStock$1.actionPerformed(ViewStock.java:50)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Please help me on this issue thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to solve JXL error : jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799059/how-to-solve-jxl-error-jxl-read-biff-biffexception-unable-to-recognize-ole-st)

Answer (score 0):

trying to read data from the Excel file saved in MS Office 2010 brings this error up. Saved the file as an `Excel 2003-07` and then it will read without any problem. or even `"Excel 97-2003 Workbook"` type will solve the issue.

Comment: i tried Office 2007 and file saved as Excel 97-2003 Workbook but it gives me same error

Comment: After using MS Office 2010 it not works it gives me same error